# Deeplink ionic3 : don't launch the app on android

Tags: android, typescript, ionic3, deeplink

I'm using the **ionic-plugin-deeplinks**

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=myapp --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=myapp.com

 npm install --save @ionic-native/deeplinks
```

I added this plugin to my app's module
in app.component.ts:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.navChild, {
        '/courseDetails/:courseID': CourseDetailsPage,
      }).subscribe((match) => {
        console.log('Successfully routed', match);
      }, (nomatch) => {
        console.log('Unmatched Route', nomatch);
      });
    });
```

I created the assetlinks.json file that contains :

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target" : { 
      "namespace": "android_app", 
      "package_name": "lb.myapp.app",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["11:11:11:1F:5D:56:11:D0:11:11:A1:91:34:98:11:EF:B2:FC:50:11:73:5E:90:18:84:13:05:C7:78:E1:A4:A5"] }
}]
```

I host this file on lb.myapp.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json.

I made **ionic cordova build android --release**, then I generated a private key, then I signed the unsigned apk and then zipalign and installed the signed apk to the android device and tried to share a link:

```
https://lb.myapp.com/main/courseDetails/123
```

The app didn't appear between the choices that I had to open the link.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

i find this error that i did by installing the plugin :
$ ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=myapp --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=**lb.myapp.com**